# wxPython change field on tab

Tags: python, wxpython

I apologize for a simple question, but I did not see this in the tutorials.

I have a very simple gui, but I would like the user to be able to press the TAB key and have it move from one input field to another.  I am using wxPython with Python 2.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should just work in the general case; what specific controls are you having issues with? You may need to pass wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL as a style, or if you need to manipulate the order, you can use the Move(After|Before)InTabOrder(otherControl) methods on the control.

See http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#How_to_get_tabs_to_work for examples of both of these techniques!

Comment: Thanks.  I changed the kwds["style"] line so it reads:
kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL